# Google Cloud: Access to image has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cors, google-cloud-storage

I deployed a website on Google Cloud via Cloud Run. The site uses Django and Webpack. The resources are automatically loaded to a Google Cloud Storage bucket.

However, when I try to load the website some resources are not loaded correctly:

```
Access to image at 'https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket-name>/bcf8ff28514bad926b0c.png' from origin '<URL of my website>' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

If I try to access the request just by copy-pasting the URL into the browser it works fine (I can see the image).

By looking at the Request Header for the resources that do not load correctly, their `Origin` is set to the URL of my website, e.g. `https://example.com`. The resources that do load correctly don't have `Origin` in the Request Header. Moreover, this issue only appears on Chrome and Safari but not on Firefox. When I inspect the Request Header on Firefox, the origin is actually set to `https://storage.googleapis.com/` (instead of `https://example.com`), which I assume it's the reason why the resources load correctly.

I guess there are two ways to solve the problem, though I don't know what solution should be preferred and how to implement it:

1. Find a way to set the Origin in the Request Header to `https://storage.googleapis.com/` on Chrome and Safari.
2. Change the settings of my Google Cloud Storage bucket so that it accepts request from `https://example.com`.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin) about CORS on Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was following [this example](https://CORS%20configuration%20examples). First, create a JSON file with the CORS configurations:

```
[
    {
      "origin": ["https://example.com"],
      "method": ["GET"],
      "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]
```

Then run the following command:

```
gcloud storage buckets update gs://BUCKET_NAME --clear-cors
```

Thank you to Doug Stevenson for pointing me in the [right direction](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin).